# How to add jquery event on opencart admin panel product list page?

Tags: jquery, opencart

OpenCart structure follows an MVC pattern. Where can I edit to add such a jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the template file, located under `admin/view/template/catalog/product_list.tpl`.

This concrete file is the template for product list in backend. At the end of the template file there should be some jQuery already present.

Comment: Another question. Which class/file is using that tpl file and sets those php variables?

Comment: It is `admin/controller/catalog/product.php`. This is same for every other feture. For each controller there is/are counter-part template/s and almost always a model class. There is a post on SO about *how to become guru in opencart* (or similar) posted by Jay Gilford, I highly recommend reading through if you are starting with opencart development...

Comment: Thanks. Is there an extensive documentation or a developer guide (not customer guide)?

Comment: None of which I know about (I mean the guide). You can find a documentation, but it is not developer (IMHO) nor extensive (last checked was begining of 2012). [But off You go](http://docs.opencart.com/display/opencart/OpenCart+1.5+Home) (looks much better now)

Comment: Aww, sorry, now I checked the *Developers* part of the documentation and it is the same shit as before... So no, there is no such guide nor documentation. Sorry.